# What characteristics would my Enslaver Aliens find attractive in each other?

Tags: science-fiction, aliens, reproduction

Each photo I have [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Fs0.jpg) is that of an Enslaver Alien. Thank you midjourney for helping me create these creatures. They are an alien species that can grow to the size of a fifteen story building and are native from a gas giant planet.

Biologically they are immortal, have two genders and can reproduce anytime of the year. They usually reproduce with a "clutch" of eight to twelve but it takes at least a decade for such "pods" to grow to size of young adulthood where they then leave or are chase out of their parents homes. They have nests that they take care off for half a year before the "clutch" hatches.

I want to show that these aliens are alien mindset but compared to the other members of the "Big Three" species they're the most relatable morality to humans. Like they're still giant creatures that see humans and other species as cattle or ants with the exceptional humans worthy of respect being less than ten.

But they're still kind of relatable in an odd way.

Two genders, child rearing, showing love/compassion to their "partner", practices life long commitment to each other and etc. But they're still Eldritch Abominations. They even do nesting and home construction but being them it's more like "I can control an entire storm and turn it into a house" rather than "cut wood make house". But they're still Eldritch Abominations.

Powers of the Enslavers include the following:

1. Floating or Flight
2. Learned Teleportation
3. Limited Weather Control
4. Telekinesis of their own Mass
5. Telepathy of thousands of human level creatures
6. Biological Immortality
7. Generation of Forcefields

Now this may seem like a lot but these are the most strongest sentient creatures of my universe. They are "naturally" evolved though and how they evolved in such a world is up to task. Enslaver brains are two parts; one that is for higher thinking one for basic thinking. This is because the brain used to be a separate species altogether until, ten million years ago, by accident the two combined together to create the first sentient, intelligent Enslaver. Every Enslaver's first brain is a dark, semi clear spot in their head.

Enslavers are also relatively violent creatures and do tend to kill each other at a magnitude higher rate than humans would in a comparative society. So if 10% of Humans died prehistorically at the hands of another human, nearly 100% of Enslavers suffer the same fate. This even translates to modern society where homicide rates are much higher than what are expected.

Comment: Paraphrasing Mr. Sir Mix-a-Lot in his seminal treatise "Baby Got Back", I assert that they'd find large posteriors most attractive in prospective mates. In the years since the publication of his study, it has bee replicated any number of times. It may well be a universal truth.

Comment: This must be a trick question introduced by the moderators to check whether the general user population can spot a blindingly obvious example of an unanswerable opinion based inquiry. To see why it is opinion based, try to list what characteristics human men find attractive in human women. Then try to find a non-trivial common sublist.

Comment: It's not a trick question. It's just something I'm now curious of. After this I'll stop asking about my species. But I'm kind of curious to know.

Comment: I'm sorry but this really doesn't sound like something properly answerable. It may or may not involve combat between males, may or may not involve bright colors and fancy decorations on partners, may or may not include elaborate dances or nests built, and especially in the case of sapient creatures like us, it can't even be affirmed to be related to signs that the partner is healthy and capable of producing strong offspring. It's really a matter of how instinctive/intelligent they are, what they and their societies value, and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sexual selection.**

[image]

Many species possess traits simply because the female of the species finds them sexy and selects for them. In the case of the peacock, all these feathers are definitely not practical when trying to escape a predator, but they do signal excellent health and an ability to gather enough resources not just to survive, but to invest into sexy bling too. Basically, there is no difference between this and other elaborate mating rituals like owning a shiny sports car.

Likewise males of many species often fight against each other to show their fitness.

So, generally, fitness is attractive, and it is judged on results.

This could explain some of the traits of your enslaver species in an elegant way.

- Telepathy of thousands of human level creatures

Showing off how many creatures one can control is definitely a plus, so sexual selection would absolutely boost evolution of this ability. If there is a nest, the male should have his creatures build it, then the female picks a winner. To woo the female, the male would offer gifts and treats (ie, creatures) and make them perform a dance, politely ask to be eaten, or cook and serve each other. Like a romantic candlelight dinner with self-serving snacks.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring how opinion based this question is, I can only point to power as of right now. Perhaps they can teleport farther, generate stronger forcefields and thats attractive. With a complete lack of knowledge of their culture I can't really say any more. Even that may not hold true, as in human society, having a partner you can rely on and that won't die is attractive (for most I think), but in theirs, they may view being strong badly.